# Compiling handlebars template using gulp but ignoring variables

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars as a templating language for creating email and print communication templates.  The templates share common elements and so I'm moved them into partials.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm looking to have a gulp task that creates a templates from the main body file and the partials but without touching the variables i.e. the output from this task should be a Handlebars template that will be used later by a different application to inject variables and send the communications.

I can't find a working gulp and handlebars package that will let me do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I complete get the scenario but it seems you can use `gulp-html-extend` to build an intermediary state that contains the main and the partials expanded. Hope it helps.

Example from the plugin:

```
master.html

<body>
    <!-- @@placeholder= content -->
    <!-- @@placeholder =footer -->
</body>

content.html

<!-- @@master  = master.html-->

<!-- @@block  =  content-->
<main>
    my content
</main>
<!-- @@close-->

<!-- @@block  =  footer-->
<footer>
    my footer
</footer>
<!-- @@close-->


output

<body>

<!-- start content -->
<main>
    my content
</main>
<!-- end content -->

<!-- start footer -->
<footer>
    my footer
</footer>
<!-- end footer -->

</body>
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I was too focused on finding a handlebars solution that I hadn't considered the idea of ignoring it's a handlebars file and just lookee to combine text files. Thanks.